# clojure How do you package jax-ws web service to war

Tags: clojure, jax-ws, leiningen

I have successfully created a JAX-WS web service in clojure using definterface and deftype. How so I package this to a war file using `lein ring uberwar` so that I can deploy it in tomcat or any other servlet container? I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could shed some more infos about your solution, i.e. whether you use ring etc. Otherwise, @Chiron is exactly right, you can generate WAR files with `lein ring uberwar`. If you want to have a dual setup in the sense of being able to use jetty/lein ring server for development and only build a WAR file for Tomcat for production, you can use different lein profiles to set this up.

Comment: @schaueho I have edited the question accordingly. `lein-ring` does not seem to package JAX-WS web service using default ring options. I have gone through the [documentation](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#compiling) and there are options we can try out.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried that as usually I package my applications as JARs and use an embedded container such as `Jetty`.

However, it looks like that [lein-ring](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) is able to generate WAR files. I never tried that but maybe it will works for you even that you aren't using Ring library.

If it not working, then it is possible to extend Leiningen to create custom tasks. Properly you can create a task to package your project as WAR file. If so, please consider releasing it on Github later!

Comment: [lein-ring](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#compiling) provides options to affect how the war file is generated. I am trying them out and if these do not work then the other remedy is to extend that plugin.